# Deploying VSIX using MSI installer getting Trust Warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I am using [VSIX Installation using MSI](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2009/10/27/vsix-and-msi.aspx) to deploy VSIX but after installation the MSI, I get the security warning every time I click on Item.

Is there anyway around to fix directly from MSI.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the text of "Trust Warning" and which item you're clicking on. A shortcut to your app's exercutable?

Comment: that is Security Warning. A message box appears which asks do you trust this template. Here is the messagebox https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6_BPuIrJGtOamZ4MTJoWlc3cUk/view?usp=sharing